# How to automatically assign USER ROLES in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create an authorization scheme that creates users based on a table in my database named `DJELATNIK` that has attributes `name, surename, korisnicko_ime, lozinka`.  `korisnicko_ime` is the username for the employee and `lozika` it's the employees password. I created a Authentication Scheme with the following Authentication Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    prijava_custom(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    v_korisnicko varchar2(100);
    v_lozinka varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT KORISNICKO_IME, LOZINKA
    INTO v_korisnicko, v_lozinka
    FROM DJELATNIK
    WHERE UPPER(KORISNICKO_IME) = UPPER(p_username)
    AND LOZINKA = p_password;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

Everything works, all the employees now have an "account" created but i still need to manually assign them a role before they can actually login.

What i want is to set all roles of the accounts generated from this scheme to be a contributor.
And somehow set my account to be administrator.
Is that even possible ?

I understand that i could add a new column in my DJELATNIK table to select role in the form for DJELATNIK but i don't know how to write the code needed to actually make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question if you are using your own roles or the native "Application Access Control".

If you're using "Application Access Control" then there is an [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/ADD_USER_ROLE-Procedure-Signature1.html#GUID-9371025F-7E1B-4C52-A8A2-EA5581BC7FC3) available to grant a user a specific role.

There are 2 options:

- Grant the user the "Contributor role" when the account is created.
- Have an after authentication application process that checks if the current user has the Contributor role and if not, then grant the user the role

Update: an alternative solution is to modify the authorisation scheme for contributor so it just checks if the user is logged on.

Comment: Yes sorry , I'm using the native Application Access Control. As i understand my code doesn't actually create an account it just checks if the username and password match. Or so i understand :D. I will look into the API you linked thank you !

Comment: Another option is to change the "Contributor" authentication scheme so that everyone who is authenticated has it - that way you don't have to explicitly add the role

Comment: How do I do any of those options? i read about the API you sent but I still don't understand if I need to do a procedure to add the Contributor role? do I do it in the code I posted? what are the steps? Or if you could tell me where to find the steps would be awesome!

Comment: The code you posted is the authentication function. It verifies if the user has access. Authentication and Authorisation are 2 very different things. That code you posted is fine and shouldn't be changed. I'm not sure what you don't understand about my answer. I listed multiple options (just updated my answer to reflect my previous comment for completeness). What option did you pick ? What is unclear about how to implement it ?